# Elasticsearch- How to make the aggregation to return only the key matched

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 6.2.3 and i'm trying to make a filter on the aggregation to return only the keys matched not all of them from the buckets. Or maybe i need to do a script and iterate over the buckets to get only the match?
My query is:

```
  {
"aggs" : {
    "genres" : {
           "nested" : {
            "path" : "tags"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "d":{
        "terms" : { "field" : "tags.values.value.facet"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "NAME": {
            "filter": {
              "prefix": {
                "tags.values.value.facet": "Variatio"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }                 
}}
```

And the result looks like that:

```
"aggregations": {
"genres": {
  "doc_count": 285391,
  "d": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 44437,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "null",
        "doc_count": 251811,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "MMAkku",
        "doc_count": 15870,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "MMBaden",
        "doc_count": 15870,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "MMEttlingen",
        "doc_count": 15870,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "MMEurope",
        "doc_count": 15870,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "MMGermany",
        "doc_count": 15870,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "MMKarlsruhe",
        "doc_count": 15870,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      }
      }
```

But i want to see only the keys that matches only the word from the filter.
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "facets": {
      "filter": {
        "prefix": {
          "tags.values.value.facet": "Variatio"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "facets_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.values.value.facet"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With this example i have no results....                                                                                                                                                "aggregations": {
"facets": {
  "doc_count": 0,
  "facets_count": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": []
  }
}

Comment: I think you should change filter term to filter prefix  please check it. I editted the answer

Comment: I changed the query but the keys result still aren't filtered:                          "aggregations": {
    "genres": {
      "doc_count": 285391,
      "facets": {
        "doc_count": 13287,
        "facets_count": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 868,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Produktbilder",
              "doc_count": 13068
            },{
              "key": "Sachaufnahme",
              "doc_count": 9642
            },{
              "key": "Katalogbild",
              "doc_count":4854} etc

Comment: I succeed to filter the buckets key with the "Include" clause. I wonder how to use Include in java?